# mt3608 not increasing voltage

Tags: voltage, circuit-design, boost

I have built on breadboard the following:

[image]

Capacitors: 22uF Inductor: 4.7 uH Voltage divider: 9.4kOhm and 4.7 KOhm

According to datasheet: https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/XI-AN-Aerosemi-Tech-MT3608_C84817.pdf

As you might notice I built all as specified in the datasheet.

But, the problem I don't get any increment in voltage, it stays about 3V (powered from an Arduino Uno).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it's incredibly hard to reason about this. Please use a *circuit schematic* instead of a *wiring diagram* to define your circuit.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's hard to reason about a circuit that's not given in schematic form, but as a wiring diagram, let's only talk about the shortcomings of that wiring diagram:

1. That's a 1.2 MHz switch frequency converter. Hence, it produces very high frequencies (multiples of the switching frequency), and breadboard is almost always a bad idea in that case, because it has high tendencies for cross-talk between adjacent tracks and radiation, and high inter-track capacitances and inductivities.
2. Your device ground has a high-impedance route back to your power source's ground: multiple centimeters of breadboard track and a long wire. That means the converter won't work well, because now you have a "swinging" ground competing with the "swinging" inductor.
3. 22uF capacitors in leaded form are almost certainly electrolytic caps with a high series resistance. These are themselves again attached using high-impedance tracks to the thing they are meant to filter/stabilize. This greatly reduces their efficiency.
4. the IC is a sot23-6 device. It's really not meant for breadboard, but SMD usage on a PCB – this is relevant because a lot of the device cooling will happen through its pins, especially towards a ground plane.

Comment: So you mean the breadboard is the real cause for the failure? Do you know any similar components suitable for breadboard prototyping?

Comment: The problem of breadboards are unrelated to the actual chip you use: fast switching = high frequencies = bad for breadboard. Hence, the solution is *not* to put the components that go with the switcher on the breadboard, but on a PCB. There's ready-made PCBs available that integrate that.

Comment: I'm only learning electronics now, and want to build my first PCB, but beforehand I thought to test it out on a breadboard. Can you suggest other ways of testing before manufacturing?

Comment: Really, really, really draw the circuit diagram, not just a breadboard wiring diagram! That's the first step in designing a PCB, anyways. So please **Edit** your question and include that circuit schematic.

Comment: DONE, it was actually the breadboard, after soldering it together on a prototype PCB board, it all works as expected. Thank you for helping!

Comment: STILL: Please do yourself the favor and have a good schematic of what you build! It's not an optional step.

Comment: This would be the exact same as in the datasheet I linked to.

Comment: which is still missing the actual component values and types you're using. Also, when designing a PCB, you typically have one workflow that takes you from the schematic editor (where you have your circuit schematic) half-automatedly to the PCB layout editor (where you actually place your components and the traces); the layout editor knows about the components and their connections from the circuit editor! So, I really don't understand why you haven't just posted a picture of the schematic diagram that you'll need to have! Anyway, I think I've said that multiple times now, and will leave now :)